# Working on GWT and App engine plugins on eclipse and found "an error occurred while trying to sign in "

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin

Today, I installed GWT and Google App Engine plugins for eclipse. Everything was working fine. But, when I click the sign to google, which is on the left bottom of eclipse screen, in my case, it come up with this error(in a message box) "an error occurred while trying to sign in 
:400 bad request. See the error log for more detail". And the error log looks like this

Message: Couldn't sign ing

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:209)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth.AbstractOAuthGetToken.execute(AbstractOAuthGetToken.java:64)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.authorizeStep1(GoogleLogin.java:535)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.logIn(GoogleLogin.java:416)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.logIn(GoogleLogin.java:379)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution$1.mouseUp(LoginTrimContribution.java:90)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:219)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

I tried to find the solution on  [google forums](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4969) but couldnt find the solution.

Can you help me please, if you encountered such problem?

FYI: I am using Eclipse Indigo and Eclipse eclipse-java-helios-SR1

**UPDATE**: Solved look the comment below.

Comment: The same thing is happening in both eclipse IDEs.

Comment: OMG ... It took me more than 24 hrs to solve this .... No body even on Google side was helping ... The solution for me was straight forward. 

I tried to deploy my first application and for that process I think it needs you to sign in to your gmail address and it couldnt sign in, even if I dont know why. But I followed the command line instruction(http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading.html) and everything was solved. Thank God ... and now I deployed my first app on GAE.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, so others can benefit from your hard-won wisdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.. No body even on Google side was helping ... The solution for me was straight forward. I tried to deploy my first application and for that process I think it needs you to sign in to your gmail address and it couldnt sign in, even if I dont know why. But I followed the command line instruction(code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/…) and everything was solved. Thank God ... and now I deployed my first app on GAE.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem, looked further into the Eclipse error logs and found that my computer's clock was different than their server's clock by 1 hour (I travel a lot).  Changed it to the time zone I was last using GAE in and it worked fine without even restarting Eclipse.  Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem right now and I fix it in a simple way.

```
Error: Log in GAE and it prompt sign up 400 bad request
Result from: Your computer timing setting
Solution: Please update your computer timing seting
```